# Discord.js - get last message from mentionned user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

is possible to get the last message of the mentionned user because when i run this

```
const membre = message.mentions.members.first()
message.channel.messages.fetch(membre.user.lastMessageID).then(msg => console.log(msg.content))
```

the output is null when the mentionned user is not me

Comment: Do the people you mention have cached messages?

Comment: null could also mean, that it found a message but it was a image ( wich obviously had no Text-Content )

Comment: that's work only for the member who execute the command.
and it's not an image because the output is the command (*lastmsg)

Comment: why don't you just use `membre.lastMessageID` instead of `membre.user.lastMessageID`?

Comment: it's the same result for `membre.lastMessageID` and `membre.user.lastMessageID` each time